# DAX: Need CALCULATE no to be affected by filters

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have a calculation in a dataset on PowerPivot:

`SUM:=CALCULATE(SUM([Data]),FILTER(ALL(Table[Month]),[Month]=[CURRENTMONTH]))`

Where:

`[Data]` is numeric

`[Month]` is a date

`[CURRENTMONTH]` is a calculation that according to today's date indicates current month

In that same table, I have an additional column named day where I have all the days of the year.`[day]`

I need the calculation not to be affected when I filter the database by day meaning I need the total of the month regardless if I filter by a specific day of the month

Any ideas?

Comment: Firstly, are we talking about Excel, dax, powerpoint, or "a database"?  You'll need to [edit] your question to provide lots more information iif anyone's going to be able to help you. Also, what have you tried so far?  Have you done some research?  Check out "[ask]" as well as "[mcve]".  There are also some great tips [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Have you got a dedicated Date table? https://powerpivotpro.com/2011/11/the-ultimate-date-table/

Answer (score 0):

This is your same calculation, but it will ignore filters on your Table[day] field.

```
SUM :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( [Data] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( Table[Month] ), [Month] = [CURRENTMONTH] ), 
    ALL ( Table[day] )
)
```